# How to have a run script with display_trace() in it for debug purposes

Tags: vlab

I have a typical sort of "run" script (below).

When I want to debug the scenario, I use VLAB GUI ... and in this instance I want the trace window open, so I have display_trace() at the end of the run script.

However, often I just want to run this scenario in batch as part of a regression test.   The problem is that VLAB throws an exception on display_trace() when in batch mode.

I don't really like the idea of

```
try:
    display_trace()
except:
    pass
```

(or even catching the specific error that is thrown) ... it just feels "messy".  What if there is a valid exception upon display_trace() that I miss?

Is there some way not to call display_trace() at all if I'm in batch mode?

---

run script:

```
from vlab import *
import os

image_path = os.path.join('o5e', 'bin','o5e_dbg.elf')

load('ecu.sim', args=['--testbench=testbench_o5e',"--image=%s" % image_path] + __args__)

# First set up MMU
add_sw_execute_breakpoint(get_address("BamExit"))
run(blocking=True)

# Then we can set breakpoints in user code space
add_sw_execute_breakpoint(get_address("init_variables"))
run(blocking=True)

# Trace stuff
vtf_sink = trace.sink.vtf("o5e.vtf")
add_trace("+src:ecu.core_system.Core0.InstrTraceMsg", sink=vtf_sink)
add_trace(get_ports("ecu.core_system.Core0", kind="bus"), sink=vtf_sink)
display_trace(vtf_sink)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "interface_mode" session property can be used to query whether VLAB was launched in "graphical" mode, where the VLAB IDE is displayed, or in "text" mode.

You could use this property to conditionally call `vlab.display_trace()`:

```py
in_graphical_mode = vlab.get_properties()["interface_mode"] == "graphical"
if in_graphical_mode:
    vlab.display_trace()
```